# VIM syntax highlighting of text files

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Vim used to syntax highlight plain text files(`*.txt`) as `conf` files if the first character of the file was a `#`. But after I updated to `8.0.3`, this feature has disappeared.
Is there a way to fix this other than the solution mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/216676/vim-syntax-highlighting-disappeared-for-text-files-txt)? i.e without modifying the file.

Comment: you mean for one file or every file? `:set ft=conf` ?

Comment: Any `*.txt` starting with a `#`

Comment: Updated my answer with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function SetConfType()
  if !empty(matchstr(getline('1'), '^#\s.*'))
    set filetype=conf
  endif
endfunction

autocmd  BufEnter *.txt call SetConfType()
```

Update:

This oneliner does not require a function. It is a little bit more elegant.

```
au BufRead * if getline(1) =~ '^#\s.*' | setlocal ft=javascript.flow | endif
```